# select top n rows for each key-value pair

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

i have a key-value pair table with a third column representing some weight. all i want to is to pick up first n rows for each pair based upon the weight value, descending.

is any main-stream sql technology supporting any natural way of doing this? or do i have to always include some hack...

example data:

```
key value   weight   
15391   22877   8    
15391   24311   7    
15391   460     7    
22634   22877   6
```

i want to select top 2 rows for each pair, i.e the result should be:

```
15391   22877   8    
15391   24311   7        
22634   22877   6
```

Comment: Do you have a unique composite index on (key, value, weight) so that there can never be two key-value pairs having the same weight? `15391   22877   8, 15391   22877   8`

Comment: @tim, actually the table is an aggregate of a previous table where there where only key-value pairs, and the weight column represents number of times the particular pair appeared. so technically, all rows are distinct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your description is misleading and what you really want is this:

```
select key, value, weight
from (
    select *,
        row_number() over(partition by key order by weight desc) rn
    from aggregated_table
) s
where rn <= 2
order by weight desc, key
```

The above will work in Postgresql and SQL Server. This will work in MySQL but not in SQL Server:

```
select key, value, (
    select weight
    from aggregated_table
    where key = s.key
    order by weight desc
    limit 1
    ) weight
from aggregated_table
union
select key, value, (
    select weight
    from aggregated_table
    where key = s.key
    order by weight desc
    limit 1 offset 2
    ) weight
from aggregated_table
order by weight desc, key
```

Comment: right, i want to find all top n values for a given key, not a given pair.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to do in Postgres:

```
select key, value, weight
from (select key, value, weight, row_number() over (partition by key, value order by weight desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
```

If you want a version that works in both MySQL and Postgres, use a correlated subquery:

```
select key, value, weight
from (select key, value, weight,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.key = t.key and t2.value = t.value and t2.weight >= t.weight
             ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
```